# Transform given inequalities

Tags: functions, inequality, geometric-inequalities

I have a problem with transforming this inequalities.

$ \frac{y}{4}\leq x^2\leq 2y\leq \frac{8}{x}$

How can you transform this to draw easily on a paper ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

1. $y = 4x^2$ is a parabola.
2. $x^2 = 2y$ is another parabola.
3. $2xy = 8$, or equivalently, $xy = 4$, is a hyperbola.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So I can multiply by x or number  only one part of this inequality ?

Comment: Consider equality (i.e. the boundaries) first.  Then determine where the region of validity of the inequality lies by considering test points.

Comment: So that form is correct ? $ y\leq 4x^2\leq y\leq \frac{4}{x}$

Comment: It should be
$$y \leq 4{x^2} \leq 8y \leq \frac{32}{x}$$
which is obtained by multiplying
$$\frac{y}{4} \leq x^2 \leq 2y \leq \frac{8}{x}$$
through by $4$.

Comment: Ok. I understand now.